# View my History activities

Tags: discussion

is it possible to view my history of posts that I have viewed. The reason I'm asking, I was unable to vote or comment in the pass, having reached a status where I can I want to go back to some post that stood out for me and vote for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have been unable to vote and comment then I doubt there is any way to go back to the posts you have visited before. In other words, if you have not taken any actions which SO records in the Activity tab then there is currently no way to track your own activity.

If you have suggested edits then those may be visible in you Activity tab on the profile page.

*You are always able to favorite questions - when you are unable to do any other activity but want to *save the post for later* you can always click the start below the score on a question.

Comment: favorite questions is the way to accomplish it. Thx